# Pushing to Vector of Vectors in Julia

Tags: vector, julia

This is using Julia 0.6

Say i have a Vector of Vectors of Ints

`x = Vector{Int64}[]
resize!(x, 10)
fill!(x, [0])`

I want to push to a selected Vector within the outer vector, but can't get it to work.

```
push!(x[1], 2)

julia> x
10-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]  
 [0, 2]
```

it ends up pushing the pair to every vector. Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there a way to push to just one selected Vector?

Working with a view of one of the vectors didn't help.

```
a = x[1]
push!(a, 3)

julia> x
10-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
 [0, 2, 3]
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: The problem is the `fill`. Initialize the array as `x = [[0] for i=1:10]`

Comment: by `fill!(x, [0])`, each element of `x` is binding to exactly the same vector `[0]` : `x[1] === x[2] # => true`, so if you mutate that `[0]`, the content of all corresponding bindings will be changed.

Comment: Is this a bug? Why does fill not copy?

Comment: It's not a bug. It's documented: "Fill array A with the value x. If x is an object reference, all elements will refer to the same object."

Comment: This is not a bug. If, for example, you say `x=Vector{Any}(); resize!(x, 10); a=SomeLargeCompositeType(); fill!(x, a)`, would you expect a to be copied?

Answer (score -2):

A `deepcopy' should help to get separate objects/arrays. However, surprisingly it does not work?!

```
julia> x = Vector{Int64}[];
julia> resize!(x, 10);
julia> fill!(x, [0])
10-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]

julia> x = deepcopy(x)
julia> push!(x[1], 2)
    10-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
```

Not was I am expecting