# Julia filling an array of array

Tags: julia

So basically I wrote this code:

```
a = [[], [], []]   # a is an array of array

#### there is some code that modified a, then I want to clear array a ####

fill!(a, [])       # set every element of a back to an empty array
push!(a[1], 1)     # modify one of the element
println(a)
```

And then, the output becomes:

```
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

This means the code `fill!(a, [])` actually fills the same array reference to every index in `a`.

Is this a bug in Julia? If this method doesn't work, what alternative solution do I have?

Comment: See comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724447/pushing-to-vector-of-vectors-in-julia) question to shed light on this behavior.

Comment: Keep in mind that `[]` is the same as `Any[]`, which creates a `Vector{Any}`. This means your code will be slow. If you know the element type of the inner vectors, specify them. E.g. `[Int[] for _ in 1:3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around, the following seems to work also:

```
v .= copy.(fill!(v,[]))
```

It is closer to the original use of `fill!`, but I've never seen it used before and so it is more of a curiousity than idiomatic Julia.

NOTE:

Appreciating the enthusiasm for this answer, I must mention that `[ [] for _ in 1:3 ]` is the faster way of getting this done. Another method is `map(_ -> [], 1:3)`. Another really nice *and efficient* method is:

```
map!(_ -> [], v, v)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ahmed says, it's not a bug. In `fill!(a, [])` you only create a single array reference, which you store in every slot of `a`. To create `a` you can either use `a= [ [], [], [] ]`, or slightly more readable:

`a = [ [] for _ in 1:3 ]`.

To clean out every entry you can use broadcasting of the function `empty!`, i.e. call `empty!` on every element of `a`:

`empty!.(a)`

This avoids creating any new arrays.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a bug even in other programming languages the `fill` method works the same.

if you want to clean your array you can simply clean it just like the declaration :

```
a = [[], [], []]
```

and if the `length` can be changed you can use `for i in 1: length(a)` and clean each item